# Replace game1 with game001 with sed nested commands

Tags: sed

```
cat 1.txt | sed -E 's,game([0-9]+),game$(printf %03d \1),g'
```

to replace `1.txt` from:

```
game1 xxx vs yyy
game11 aaa vs bbb
```

to:

```
game001 xxx vs yyy
game011 aaa vs bbb
```

but the result is:

```
$ echo "game1 xxx vs yyy" | sed -E 's,game([0-9]+),game$(printf %03d \1),g'
game$(printf %03d 1) xxx vs yyy
```

How to make `printf %03d \1` correctly evaluated?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double quotes when you need substitution

```sh
sed -E "s,game([0-9]+),game$(printf %03d \1),g" 1.txt
```

**Edit:**

And, I don't think `sed` can pass value of `\1` to external commands. `perl` can help in this case:

```sh
$ cat 1.txt 
game1 xxx vs yyy
game11 aaa vs bbb
game21 aaa vs bbb

$ sed -E "s,game([0-9]+),game$(printf %03d \1),g" 1.txt 
game001 xxx vs yyy
game001 aaa vs bbb
game001 aaa vs bbb

$ # can also use: perl -pe 's/game\K\d+/sprintf "%03d", $&/ge'
$ perl -pe 's/game([0-9]+)/sprintf "game%03d", $1/ge' 1.txt 
game001 xxx vs yyy
game011 aaa vs bbb
game021 aaa vs bbb
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't combine shell commands and sed backreferences like this (and if you could, you'd have to double quote the sed command, see other answer). The shell would try to evaluate the command before sed sees it, but `\1` wouldn't mean anything to the shell.

You can do it as follows, though:

```
$ sed -E 's/^(game)([[:digit:]]+)/\100\2/;s/^(game).{0,2}([[:digit:]]{3})/\1\2/' 1.txt
game001 xxx vs yyy
game011 aaa vs bbb
```

The first substitution, `s/^(game)([[:digit:]]+)/\100\2/`, adds two zeros in front of the digits after `game`:

```
$ sed -E 's/game([[:digit:]]+)/game00\1/' 1.txt
game001 xxx vs yyy
game0011 aaa vs bbb
```

The second substitution, `s/^(game).{0,2}([[:digit:]]{3})/\1\2/` removes up to two characters between `game` and three digits that follow it, to get rid of unwanted extra zeros.

Notice that

- I've used `/` instead of `,` as delimiter, just because I'm more used to it.
- I've anchored `game` at the start of the line with `^`.
- I've used one more capture group for `game` so I don't have to type it twice per command.
- I've used the POSIX character class `[[:digit:]]` instead of `[0-9]`.
- I've used `sed '<command>' 1.txt` instead of `cat 1.txt | sed '<command>'` to avoid the [useless use of `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html).

Comment: Thanks for solution with sed!

Answer (score 0):

Just use awk:

```
$ awk '{sub(/game/,""); $1=sprintf("game%03d",$1)} 1' file
game001 xxx vs yyy
game011 aaa vs bbb
```

or in general to operate on saved capture groups with GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(game)([0-9]+)(.*)/,a){ printf "%s%03d%s\n", a[1], a[2], a[3] }' file
game001 xxx vs yyy
game011 aaa vs bbb
```

With sed you'd need:

```
$ sed -E 's/(game)([0-9]) /\10\2 /; s/(game)([0-9]{2}) /\10\2 /' file
game001 xxx vs yyy
game011 aaa vs bbb
```